# Why is the universe so stable and consistent?

Tags: cosmology, universe, solar-system, stability

Why is it we can discover patterns? Like math, chemistry, physics, biology, etc.
Why does the universe never fail us? For example in one second I'm standing next to you, the next I'm still standing there due to gravity. It's not like gravity suddens disappears and I'm flying somewhere or that I suddenly turn into a gas or something unpredictable with no pattern no laws just energy flying everywhere.

What's the cause for all the consistency and stability?
What happened at the big bang or before it that gave us a universe that works this way? Where we can have stable lives. Build communities. Experience consciousness. Learn, etc.

Why do the physics constants remain the same as when they were set initially? What set them?

Comment: There's not really an answer fto this, but worth reading if you have not is Eugene Wigner's essay "The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences." https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. @Andrew

Answer (score 1):

This is a philosophy question.

> Why is the universe so stable and consistent?

The simple answer is: It has to be. Because if it were not, we would not be here discussing about the universe. i.e. observational fact.

Physics is about observing nature , tabulating measurements and forming mathematical models that fit the measurements and in addition predict new measurements. To do this extra axioms are used, called postulates, principles, laws... to pick up the correct mathematical solutions. So "why" can be answered within physics models, until one hits on the basic axioms, and then the answer is "because that is what is observed".

> What's the cause for all the consistency and stability?

See the answer to the title.

> What happened at the big bang or before it that gave us a universe that works this way? Where we can have stable lives. Build communities. Experience consciousness. Learn, etc.

see the answer to the title

> Why do the physics constants remain the same as when they were set initially?

They remain the same within the accuracy of our measurements in space, and time. They might  be changing, and future physics will record it. It is only rapid changes we can exclude, for the reason that we would not be here to be discussing this.

> What set them?

See the answer to the title.

Answer (score 0):

Physics studies how the universe behaves. Why it does so is outside the scope of physics. Never the less, there are a couple of things that can be said.

Consider a pot of water. It just sits there. Raise the temperature. Now it boils. As long as the temperature (and other properties) stays the same, the water stay the same.

You can say the same thing about the universe. As long as some fundamental nature of the universe stay the same, the laws and constants stay the same. You could turn this around. They might well stay the same because nothing changes them.

It is a bit of a tautology. The point I am trying to make is that the universe is stable and consistent because nothing changes its fundamental nature.

---

Another thing that might be said is more or less the opposite.

Consider a pot of water. It just sits there.

But if you look at it microscopically, it is a bunch of molecules in constant motion. It is always changing, never still. what you see is an average of properties that change so fast you can't follow them.

Here I have in mind quantum fluctuations on the Planck scale.